# Compare value from previous record

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

How can I compare value from previous records?

Table:

```
ID    SAMPLEDATE    LEVEL    PASSED
1     1/1/2016      0        1
2     1/2/2016      1        1
3     1/3/2016      2        0
4     1/4/2016      1        1
5     1/5/2016      2        0
```

Is the last record (ordered by `SAMPLEDATE`) the same `LEVEL` as the last record that failed?  If yes, return TRUE otherwise return FALSE.

So in my example data the last record that failed with `LEVEL` 2. Then the last record (before the 1/5/2016 record) that failed on 1/3/2016 was the same LEVEL, so TRUE would be returned.  If it was a different LEVEL FALSE would be returned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assumed that "failed" means `passed = 0`.

There are some detail missing from the question, i.e. do we need to compare the very last row (when ordered by `sampledate`) with the previously last "failed" row? If yes, then the following query will do:

```
with last_row as
( select top (1) sampledate, level
  from dbo.tablex
  -- where failed = 0 
  order by sampledate desc
)
select top (1) result =
    case when t.level = r.level 
        then 1 else 0
    end 
from dbo.tablex as t
  join last_row as r 
  on t.sampledate < r.sampledate
where t.passed = 0
order by t.sampledate desc ;
```

---

If, on the other side, we want to compare the last "failed" row with the previous "failed" row, then we could uncomment the `where failed = 0` line above or use the less complicated, just find the last 2 failed rows and compare their levels with a simple `group by`:

```
with last_2_failed_rows as
( select top (2) sampledate, level
  from dbo.tablex
  where failed = 0 
  order by sampledate desc
)
select result =
    case when min(level) = max(level) 
        then 1 else 0
    end 
from last_2_failed_rows ;
```